# Starting Multiple Visual Studio 2012 Web Applications in Tabs of a Single Browser Instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have two ASP.NET MVC 4 projects in a single solution in Visual Studio 2012. I have the solution set to use multiple startup projects, with the action set to Start. When I click the Start toolbar button, each project starts in a different Internet Explorer browser window.

But I'd like the two projects to start in two tabs of a single browser instance. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is:

Add a simple view in one of your projects with essentially empty html. Set that project to launch the simple view as its startup page, and set the other projects to "Don't open a page, wait for a request".

In the head section of that empty view, add the following javascript script section:

```html
<script>
  // to open another project in a newtab (works in IE)
  window.open('http://localhost:<otherprojectport>/otherprojectpage', 'tab1');
  // As many of these as you like as well, to open other actions/pages from this project:
  window.open('@Url.Action("Edit", "User", new { id=1 })', 'tab2'); // note different name
  // and to open a third page in the original tab that opens:
  document.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "User")';
</script>
```

It is the only way I have found to do it, so far, and anyway I find it easier to edit a single view than multiple project property pages to change the tabs that open.

You may have to tell your browser that it's ok for your site to open popups. To do that, just exclude the `document.location` line the first time you run it, and it will tell you it blocked a popup so you can then "always allow them" for your site.

*Footnote*

If you then want to use the chrome launcher as well the only solution I found was to do the above but use an extension (such as "One Window", which I am not endorsing, nor claiming is secure, don't blame me if your computer leaves home if you use it) to stop the pages loading as separate popups.